# Send String + Int data through Bluetooth Arduino

Tags: android, terminal, bluetooth, arduino

I am new to Arduino and I have been working on a problem that has been troubling me for a few days.

I have an Arduino Uno and an HC-05 Bluetooth module.

Basically I want to send String and Int data together through Bluetooth.

**CODE**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>        
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(10, 11); // RX | TX

void setup(void) {
  // Arduino setup
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // setting the baud rate of bluetooth
  BTSerial.begin(38400); // HC-05 default speed in AT command more
}

void loop(void) {
  int num = 123;
  BTSerial.write("#"); // Works
  BTSerial.write(num); // works
  BTSerial.write(String(num) + "#");
  // Error: no matching function for call to 'SoftwareSerial::write(StringSumHelper&)'
}
```

Also the result string should have '#' character at last.

According to the Arduino [Website](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write), it has 2 functions.

```
 - Serial.write(val) 
 - Serial.write(str)
```

Any help appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

write is for sending raw bytes.  You want to use Serial.print instead.

Comment: how can i send data through bluetooth using Serial.print

Comment: Seriously?  Have you tried just BTSerial.print(someVariable);

Comment: When you wanna send a string, you gotta use BTSerial.print().

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send a String from another device to Arduino, your code should be like this:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BT(3, 4); 
String bt = "";
void setup() {
  BT.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
}
void loop() {
  if(BT.available()){
    bt = BT.readString();
  }
  Serial.println(bt);
  while(!BT.available());
}
```

the above code waits for your Bluetooth module to receive any data, reads a String from it and prints it in Serial.

To send Int, you can read a String and parse it to Int.

Comment: I think the question asks for sending the string over Bluetooth connection, not to the Serial monitor